# Como acceder a mi servidor virtual Linux que tengo en Docker desde afuera

Tags: linux, ubuntu, servidor, docker

tengo en mi NAS un servidor creado en docker en el que le he estado instalando apache y tal, y para probar y que me muestre la pagina de test index.html que tiene apache2 estaba intentao acceder desde mi pc personal a la ip que me pone al hacer ifconfig al servidor cuando me conecto por ssh. Pero es una ip local, **¿Que tendria que hacer para conectarme desde mi pc al apache del servidor virtual que esta alojado en el NAS?**

Al hacer ifconfig en mi servidor virtual me pone lo siguiente:

```
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet xx.xx.xx.xx  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast xx.xx.xx.xx
        ether xx.xx.xx.xx txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 14747  bytes 22240737 (22.2 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 11113  bytes 950588 (950.5 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet xx.xx.xx.xx  netmask 255.0.0.0
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Comment: A qué te quieres conectar al contenedor docker?

Comment: Pues que como puedo ver desde otro pc de la misma red el servidor apache que esta dentro de mi servidor virtual creado en docker. a eso me refiero. @JackNavaRow

Answer (score 0):

Lo mejor que puedes hacer es crear una redirección de puerto con docker, esto es tu arrancas un contenedor con por ejemplo

```
docker run -p 80:80 nginx
```

este código o que hace es crearte un servidor web nginx y lo que hace es redirigir el puerto 80 de tu PC al 80 del contenedor de forma que si por ejemplo tu PC tiene una ip 192.168.1.34 ahora si pones esa ip te va a llevar al contenedor